# Validar palabra ingresada por teclado, mayúscula y máximo 10 caracteres

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo validar una palabra que me ingresan por teclado para que solo acepte palabras cuyo largo no sea mayor a 10 y sean mayúsculas?

Llevo probando varios métodos y ninguno me estuvo dando resultado, lo último que hice fue esto y tampoco me funciona, sin embargo en consola no me tira ningún error.

```js
function agregarPalabra(){
    var abecedario = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    var palabCorrec = false;
    var palabra = prompt("Ingrese una palabra: ").toUpperCase();

    while(!palabCorrec){
        for(var i= 0; i <palabra.length; i++){
            if(!(abecedario.includes(palabra[i]))){
                palabCorrec = false;
            }else if(palabra.length > 10){
                palabCorrec = false;
            }else{
                palabCorrec = true;
            }
        }
        if (!palabCorrec){
            palabra = prompt("Ingrese una palabra: ").toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer la validación puedes usar una regex como `/^\p{Lu}{0,10}$/gu` en donde `p{Lu}` indica cualquier letra de cualquier lenguage en mayúscula (siempre que pueda tener mayúscula). Obviamente podrías restringirlo mas si quieres.

```js
palabra = prompt("Ingrese una palabra: ");

const res = /^\p{Lu}{0,10}$/gu.test(palabra);

alert(res && "La pabra es correcta" || "La palabra no es correcta");
```